# OCMock stub class methods of the class that is being tested

Tags: ocunit, ocmock

```
+(NSString *) classMethod:(id)someDataObject
{
    NSString *returnStr;

    //do something with someDataObject and set returnStr
    //...    

    returnStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", returnStr,[self getCurrentTimestamp]];

    return returnStr;
}

+ (NSString *)getCurrentTimestamp
{
    NSNumber *t = [NSNumber numberWithLong:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
    return [t stringValue];
}
```

I am struggling to write test case for the classMethod because when I run OCUnit test and pass OCMock object to classMethod the output will be always different as I add timestamp. What is the best approach to *stub* class method - getCurrentTimestamp? Is it actually possible to stub class methods of the class that is being tested?

I tried like this, but it is not working:

```
 id mock =  [OCMockObject mockForClass:[MyClass class]];
 [[[mock stub] andReturn:@1378468455] getCurrentTimestamp];

 NSString *str = [MyClass classMethod:someMockObject];
```

Comment: I notice your stub is returning an NSNumber and not and NSString -- not sure if that is the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @BenFlynn. Your example (as well as mine) is working indeed. The problem was that "MyClass.h" was checked in Target Membership for the unite test too. "MyClass.h" should target only project (I am not sure why, maybe someone can explain it).

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
+(NSString *) classMethod:(id)someDataObject
{
    NSString *returnStr = @"prefix-";
    returnStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", returnStr,[self getCurrentTimestamp]];
    return returnStr;
}

+ (NSString *)getCurrentTimestamp
{
    NSNumber *t = [NSNumber numberWithLong:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
    return [t stringValue];
}

- (void)testClass
{
    id mock =  [OCMockObject mockForClass:[Bar class]];
    [[[mock stub] andReturn:@"1378468455"] getCurrentTimestamp];   
    NSString *str = [Bar classMethod:nil];
    NSLog(@"Str: %@", str);
}

// Result: 
// Str: prefix-1378468455
```

Can you confirm your OCMock version, change the number to a string, and / or explain how it is not working for you?

Comment: Hey @Ben Flynn you seem like a good guy.. check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287673/cannot-stub-class-method-with-ocmock) very similar problem