# NSObject class method returns pointer instead of class in Unit Test target

Tags: objective-c, class, unit-testing

I noticed that for only one of my classes, the `+(Class)class` method does not return the proper value when I'm unit testing.

```
Class class1 = [DiscoverCell class];//(Class) 0xd264d60
Class class2 = NSClassFromString(@"DiscoverCell");//(Class) DiscoverCell
STAssertEquals(class1, class2, nil);
```

Here is the .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class DiscoverItem;

@interface DiscoverCell : UITableViewCell

+ (CGFloat)getHeightWithItem:(DiscoverItem *)item;

- (void)setupWithItem:(DiscoverItem *)item;

@end
```

I've tried it with other subclasses and they all work fine. It just seems to be this class.

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: Well, `Class` is a type that holds pointers to class objects, so that is not saying much. Do you have multiple `DiscoverCell` classes or something? So `class1 == class2` is false? Are you doing something weird that could cause classes to be loaded more than once or something? What about `Class class3 = objc_getClass("DiscoverCell")`?

Comment: @newacct thanks for the response! yes `class1 != class2`. I only have 1 `DiscoverCell` class (i do have a class extension for it for private methods but i don't think that would affect it). Not sure what weird thing i could do for it to be loading more than once... `class3` return the correct value `(Class) DiscoverCell`.

Comment: hmm.. you don't happen to have a variable somewhere named `DiscoverCell`, do you? Does `[DiscoverCell self]` give the same thing as `[DiscoverCell class]`? Are both `[class1 description]` and `[class2 description]` the string `DiscoverCell`? Does `[class1 class]` equal `class1`? and `[class2 class]` equal `class2`? Could you isolate this into a small project that you can upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. The DiscoverCell target membership included my app target and the test target. So there was a directly linked AND a dynamically generated class from OCMock. Fixed it by setting the target membership for only my app target.

[cannot stub class method with OCMock 2.1+ in Xcode 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287673/cannot-stub-class-method-with-ocmock-2-1-in-xcode-5-0)